# EBS Auto SnapShot Scheduler on AWS not taking snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

Followed "http://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ebs-snapshot-scheduler/deployment.html" for scheduling EBS backups on daily basis, with a retention period of 15 days.
But, no snapshots are taken as scheduled. The instances are tagged correctly with custom tag key "scheduler:ebs-snapshot", but the event logs show "No snapshots taken" for the specified time for snapshot.

Do anyone faces similar issues? Any help/support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your tag definition?

Comment: I think "scheduler:ebs-snapshot" should be the tag key as per AWS. It dosen't work. I also tried this way:  "tag-key"="scheduler" and "value"="ebs-snapshot"

Comment: The key should be 'scheduler:ebs-snapshot', with the value 'default' or 'true'. The next step is to look at the CloudWatch logs, something like '/aws/lambda/ebs-snapshot-scheduler-*. If there are no logs, you might check that the CloudFormation template completed successfully.